# Split the dataframe with a minimal way in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 10 different dataframe with shape 1000*1000. I have to use a part of this data frames for the training and validation. Now I am using the following lines of code to separate this dfs:

```
 df1_train = df1.loc[:, Start:end]
 df2_train = df2.loc[:,Start:end]
 df3_train = df3.loc[:,Start:end] 
 ...
```

And this make a lot of lines of codes. I am looking for a more minimal way to do this. Do you know any option in the pandas or numpy for this? Thank you

Comment: This is not very many lines. Are you sure you need to change _anything_?

Comment: I only put three here, the total is 20 lines.

Comment: How did you end up with 10/20 dataframes? Better put them in a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=globals#globals) :

```
list_dfs = ["df1", "df2", .. ]

for df in list_dfs:
    globals()[f"{df}_train"] = eval(df).loc[:, Start:end]
```

Or, if the dataframes names have the same pattern (*which is the case here*), use this :

```
N = 10 # <- number of dataframes

for i in range(N):
    df_name = f"df{i+1}"
    globals()[f"{df_name}_train"] = eval(df_name).loc[:, Start:end]
```

Comment: Thank you. with this way, when I want to print the df1_train, this error shows up "NameError: name 'df1_train' is not defined!

Comment: My bad, we need to make a list of the df names and not the dfs themselves. Can you try again ?

Comment: You're welcome. If you have dozens of dataframes, I added another approach so you avoid making a long list of variable names ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
orig_dfs = [df1, ..., dfn]
train_dfs = []
for df in orig_dfs:
        train_dfs.append(df.loc[:, start:end])
```